# Build project android cocos2d-x error

Tags: android, android-ndk, httpclient, cocos2d-x

I created multi platform project by cocos2d-x, I'm coding and building on iOS successfuly, but when I build it on Android, project 's error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'will' does not name a type mPlay       line 1, external location: /Volumes/DATA/ToolMacOS/Android/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/deque.tcc  C/C++ Problem
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos_extension_static/network/HttpClient.o] Error 1  mPlay           C/C++ Problem

Please help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention which release are you using? and what is your android SDK version? Try using 3.0 alpha or one of the latest stable releases.